# how to remove serial numbers from string in R

Tags: r

How to remove serial number from text in R:

Sample data:

`a=data.frame(text=c("1.This can be achieved using xyz method.  2. It consists of various steps. 3. For more details, check this website))`

Expected result:

```
This can be achieved using xyz method. It consists of various steps.
For more details, check this website.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `sub` here:

```
input <- "1.This can be achieved using xyz method.  2. It consists of various steps. 3. For more details, check this website"
input <- gsub("\\d+\\.\\s*", "", input)

[1] "This can be achieved using xyz method.  It consists of various steps. For more details, check this website"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with `stringr` package  and the `str_remove_all` function

```
> text <- c("1.This can be achieved using xyz method.  2. It consists of various steps. 3. For more details, check this website")
> stringr::str_remove_all(text, "\\d+\\.\\s?")
[1] "This can be achieved using xyz method.  It consists of various steps. For more details, check this website"
```